# Ubuntu 16.10 - Off-pixel font rendering on ultra wide screen

Tags: display, fonts, hdmi, display-resolution

Ubuntu renders text 'off-pixel' at full resolution on my wide screen monitor. For example, and 'l' that uses a single pixel line, will often do sub-pixel rendering causing it to draw if on two pixels. This causes a kind of fringing that makes a black 'l' appear half red, half grey.

For now I've dropped down to a custom resolution to makes this effect less annoying. So instead of using the full 3440 x 1440 resolution, I am now using 2944 x 1260. This helps a lot, but looses screen real-estate and is not really the correct solution.

I've tried both the default drivers and the 3'rd party display drivers. Both have the same problem.

Hardware Specifications:

- Monitor: [Samsung 34" SE790 Curved WQHD Monitor Ultra-wide Screen](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/curved/34-ultra-wide-curved-screen-monitor-ls34e790cns-za/) used at 60 Hz over HDMI.
- Machine: [Dell XPS 15 9550](http://www.dell.com/nz/p/xps-15-9550-laptop/pd)
- Video Card: [NVIDIA GeForce® GTX 960M with 2GB GDDR5](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-960m)

I've verified that small fonts are crisp on another machine, so the monitor is fine.

Comment: Please edit and add hardware specs.

Comment: Hardware specs added :-)

Comment: Have you installed proprietary drivers for the Nvidia?